# Using Refresh Token simply gets the same, existing access token

Tags: rest-api, refresh-token

I followed the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5) for getting a refresh token as part of my initial OAuth2 web server flow by including the refresh token scope. I then followed the refresh token flow [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5). I also looked at the advice given in this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/238683/123311).

Each time I go through the stages I get data back successfully. However, in the final refresh I always get the same access token back. I am not getting a new one. Is this because it is still valid? That being said I have tried after a while when I know the access token is invalid and I still get the same one back.

Has anybody seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. If the previous access token is valid, you will get the same token again. If I remember correctly, the refresh token has the same behavior; as long as the token is valid, you'll get the same refresh token as well. If you want to test a changing access token, you'll have to manually revoke it or wait for it to expire. You can set the Session Duration to 15 minutes so you don't have to wait long to see the effect.

Comment: Where do I set the session duration? Or revoke the session?

Comment: @zeiddev To change the duration, Setup > Security > Session Settings, or you can override in a profile or permission set. For revoking, Setup > Security > Session Management.